# Can't create numerical column with decimal positions using SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

The following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (TESTFIELD dec(6,2))
```

throws an error SQL0104:

> Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: AS NO FOR NOT FILE WITH CCSID CHECK LOGGED UNIQUE COMPACT DEFAULT.

It works fine when I eliminate the decimal positions `( ,2 )`.

This is not a SQL error. There must be a configuration gap on the machine (V7R2M0). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have comma configured as decimal separator.

In this case you have the sort of problems you described and `values (1,1)` gives one row/one column with value `1.1` while `values (1, 1)` gives one row/two columns with both value 1

You have to either switch to period as a the decimal separator or put a space after every comma following a number if you don't want to be interpreted as decimal number if it's followed by a number.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (TESTFIELD dec(6, 2))
```

Comment: that query is that what he has already tried

Comment: @nbk well he wrote `dec(6,2)` thows sql0104 and that it works when he eliminates the decimal positions, that means he tried `dec(6)` to me but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: that is why we haven't posted any answer, as the query works and we can't reproduce it

Comment: @nbk Can you connect to a AS400/Iseries/IBMi ? Then try with comma as decimal separator and you will see the behavior described. My country uses comma as a decimal separator and that the main reason why I put a blank after every comma of every query.

Comment: The SQL client might also have something to do with it. I see this error in the USA with dBeaver when there is not a space after the comma, even though the decimal separator here is a period (.). SQuirreL does not do this. As a result I always include a space after commas.