# Token not valid creating and inserting in a table

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

In DB2 for AS/400, I've created a table EMPLEADO that consists of three columns (codigo, nombre, sueldo). First I cannot create a column as a decimal type for example: SUELDO DECIMAL(9,2) because I get a token not valid error.

Then I try to insert a new row like this:

```
 INSERT INTO EMPLEADO(CODIGO,NOMBRE,SUELDO)
 VALUES(1523698,'JOHN DOE',2500)
```

I get another error message:

```
 Token 'JOHN DOE' was not valid. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >
```

I am using PUB400, is it a db2 performance error for this public server? Or what is the correct syntax?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create numerical column with decimal positions using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704342/cant-create-numerical-column-with-decimal-positions-using-sql) I tried on PUB400 and it answered both the problem with the DECIMAL column and the INSERT statrment

Comment: It is not a decimal(9,2) in the CREATE TABLE so there is an inconsistency between text and SQL. Try a blank after the column separating commas and use 'JOHN DOE' with single parenthesis. You could also try 2500. as decimal equals deciamal(5,0)